# Completely disable REST API

Tags: cuba-platform

What's the most secure way to completely disable Cuba REST API, so that I can only use the Portal Module to manually expose endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove `rest_api` servlet in web and portal (if exists) modules, i.e. delete the following lines from `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest_api</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.haulmont.restapi.sys.CubaRestApiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest_api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```